# How to change playback speed in Adobe Audition during editing

Tags: adobe-audition

Is it possible to the change the playback speed in Adobe Audition during editing and have it correct the pitch so only the tempo changes. For editing a podcast, I want to listen faster than real time without doing any destructive edits.

Just using J, K and L are *ok* but the higher pitch makes it difficult to listen to.

Comment: +1. I've been shocked that either this feature doesn't exist or isn't obvious or talked about.  It seems like everyone would want to use it every single time.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a video that goes through how to speed it up without affecting the pitch.

Here are the steps:

1. Enable Global Clip Stretching
2. Select All tracks
3. Drag the triangle on the top right of a track that will stretch and reduce to the speed you want.
4. Once you're done editing, remember to stretch it back to it's normal speed.

Answer (score 0):

this is the main reason I cut with a video editing too first (like screenflow). I use jkl all the time to navigate through a podcast episode... and I can't find a reason why Adobe doens't just implem